# Has anyone successfully installed HAZUS MR4?

Tags: sql-server, arcgis-9.3, hazus

I am attempting to install [HAZUS-MH](http://www.fema.gov/plan/prevent/hazus/) MR4 (v1.4) on a Windows XP SP3 computer with ArcGIS 9.3 SP1 installed.  The installation seems to be running fine up until it attempts to start services.  Then it displays this error message:

[image]

I realize it's a bit of a long shot, but has anyone else installed HAZUS, recieved this error and found a successful solution for it?  I've pretty much exhausted the solutions on the FEMA site, and am hoping someone may have a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: BTW - MR-5 is out, we have been having a ton of issues getting HAZUS to work on Win7 64bit and Citrix on 2008R2 OS. MR-5 does not change that -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has your password expired and been changed (domain) lately? Similar incident with other software for me. I had to go to the sqlserver service and change the logon credentials.

Otherwise do you have a pre-existing mssql installation? And can you access the instance in the server management studio successfully?

Comment: I'm installing this for another user, which I think is leading to some of the problems.  I'll take a look at the logon credentials, that's probably a good place to start.

Comment: I finally got this to work by deleting all of the old HAZUS program files, uninstalling SQL Server, then deleting all of the SQL server folders under Program Files.  Not a login issue, but definitly a SQL Server issue.